# MappingException when I set my entity for provider section

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I got this error

```
MappingException: The class 'Telnet\IPBBridgeBundle\Entity\Member' was not found in the chain configured namespaces Telnet\CSSBundle\Entity
```

I have 2 bundles with entities and several connections into doctrine config

```
orm:
    default_entity_manager: site
    entity_managers:
        site:
            connection: siteConfig
            mappings:
                CSSBundle: ~
        forum:
            connection: forumConfig
            mappings:
                IPBBridgeBundle: ~
```

and this into provider

```
providers:
    main:
        entity: { class: Telnet\IPBBridgeBundle\Entity\Member, property: username }
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: When i replace Member entity to CSSBundle - no errors. I can't understand, where it found CSSBundle namespace

Answer (score 0):

SecurityBundle use default Entity Manager, and Entity, that implements UserInterface must be handled by default Entity Manager.